# Laravel new project

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I am making a new Laravel project using:

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel\laravel moofoo 5.2.29
```

And it gives me this error

> [Seld\JsonLint\ParsingException]
>     "./composer.json" does not contain valid JSON
>     Parse error on line 5:
>     ...        }        "scripts":{    "pos
>     -------------------^
>     Expected one of: 'EOF', '}', ',', ']'**

I tried deleting the `--prefer-dist` part and deleting composer and install it again and the problem is still there.

PS: I made a new project yesterday and it worked fine.

Comment: I do not think this is the cause, but you `laravel\larvel` should be using a slash, not backslash: `laravel/laravel`.

Comment: Seems to be an issue with your composer.json file, possibly UTF8 or odd characters towards the end of the file.

Comment: i tried using the forward slash not working , then i opened the composer.json file and deleted some scripts were there and it worked thanks guys.

Comment: May I ask you why do you require such and old Laravel version?

Answer (score -1):

Please use this:

composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel moofoo 5.2.29

Must be use slash (/). Don't use backslash ().

Don't forget to keep/check composer.phar file locate in your root/htdocs folder.

TIA

Comment: They stated that attempting to use a forward slash didn't help way earlier.